# OrderBy CLOUD_FIRESTORE

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, map, google-cloud-firestore

Buenas Noches con todos.

tengo una vista para Agendar citas, cuando reservo una cita esta se elimina en tiempo real en todos los Dispositivos.

pero tengo un problema no se me carga en orden las horas, como en la imagen[image: sin Order By]

sé que le puedo agregar un orderby, pero cuando le agrego el orderBy tengo que actualizar la lista para que este desaparezca.

como puedo hacer para que el orderby no congele la lista?

o si me pueden ayudar a ordenar este mapa por el "time" les agradecería mucho.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Schedules {
  final String order;
  final String adress;
  final String date;
  final String time;
  final String dnip;
  final String imaged;
  final String imagep;
  final String lastnamedoc;
  final String lastnamep;
  final String namedoc;
  final String namep;
  final String state;
  final DocumentReference reference;
  Schedules.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map['order'] != null),
        assert(map['adress'] != null),
        assert(map['date'] != null),
        assert(map['time'] != null),
        assert(map['dnip'] != null),
        assert(map['imaged'] != null),
        assert(map['imagep'] != null),
        assert(map['lastnamedoc'] != null),
        assert(map['lastnamep'] != null),
        assert(map['namedoc'] != null),
        assert(map['namep'] != null),
        assert(map['state'] != null),
        order= map['order'],
        adress= map['adress'],
        date= map['date'],
        time= map['time'],
        dnip= map['dnip'],
        imaged= map['imaged'],
        imagep= map['imagep'],
        lastnamedoc= map['lastnamedoc'],
        lastnamep= map['lastnamep'],
        namedoc= map['namedoc'],
        namep= map['namep'],
        state= map['state'];
  Schedules.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
  @override
  String toString() => "Record<$order:$adress:$date:$time:$dnip:$imaged:$imagep:$lastnamedoc:$lastnamep:$namedoc:$namep:$state>";
}
```

Aqui Inicializo el Stream con el OrderBy para luego utilizarlo en el StreamBuilder y en este mando a crear la Lista.

[image: el stream con el orderBy]

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context,List<DocumentSnapshot> data) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        children: data.map((data) => _buildListItem(context,data)).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

y así tengo estructurado mi _buildlistItem que toma los datos que primero almaceno en el mapa de la clase Schedules

```
Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context,DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final record = Schedules.fromSnapshot(data);
    return Container(
      key: ValueKey(record.reference.documentID),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.grey[300])
        ),
      ),
      child: Slidable(
        actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
        enabled: true,
        actionExtentRatio: 0.40,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        record.time,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF0A0909),
                          fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                          fontSize: 2.6 * size_config.textMultiplier,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        record.date.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                          fontSize: 2.2 * size_config.textMultiplier,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:3.5 * size_config.heightMultiplier,
                                left: 2 * size_config.widthMultiplier,right: 2 * size_config.widthMultiplier),
                            child: Icon(Icons.add_circle,
                                size: (2.50 * size_config.imageSizeMultiplier),
                                color: Color(0xFF43D6C0)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Disponible',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF0A0909),
                          fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                          fontSize: 2.6 * size_config.textMultiplier,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Desliza para Agendar',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          fontFamily: 'BalooMedium',
                          fontSize: 2.2 * size_config.textMultiplier,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    size: (4.50 * size_config.imageSizeMultiplier),
                    color: Colors.grey[400]),
        ),
        secondaryActions: <Widget>[
          IconSlideAction(
            caption: 'Agendar Cita',
            color: Colors.green[500],
            icon: Icons.check_circle,
            onTap: () {
              _showAlertDialog(record.namedoc,record.lastnamedoc,record.date,record.time,record.reference);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: agrega la parte donde haces orderby

Comment: @diegoveloper Muchas Gracias por querer ayudarme ya actualicé la pregunta

Comment: no la veo actualizada

Comment: @diegoveloper lo siento amigo me decía que tenia mucho código y que necesitaba mas texto entonces le tuve que hacer así, espero me puedas ayudar Muchas Gracias de AnteMano

Comment: algo que podrías hacer es evitar el orderBy, y ordenarlo tu mismo cuando recibes los datos :)

Comment: @diegoveloper disculpa no sé como pedirlo sin sentirme incomodo, me podrías indicar como porfavor? Muchas Gracias.

Comment: hmm necesitas repasar más sobre Streams, StreamSubscription , no deberías tener la conexión en tu widget, deberías tener una clase donde tengas la lógica del negocio, ahí es donde podrías consumir los datos escuchar en un stream y preprocesarlo (ordenandolo) , para que le envies el resultado al widget y pueda mostrar los datos. 
Suena complejo, pero necesitas empezar por las bases.

Comment: @diegoveloper Muchas Gracias entonces voy a revisar la información de lo sugerido, que estes bien una buena tarde.